# Why Enum constructor can't have protected or public access modifier

Tags: java, enums

Enum constructors must be either private or package default, and protected or public access modifier is not allowed. Why so

Comment: Why - if you could (and you cannot) - would you want to construct an enum from outside its definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself.

It doesn't make sense to be able to create new instances of an enum, so the language prevents you from doing so!

Comment: Nope they are like interfaces but special interfaces

Comment: @MarkBakker: Enums are like interfaces?

Comment: Well Enums are replacements for static final strings. What I mean they are like interfaces you can't initiate a interface or enum.

Comment: Actually enum can have a marker interface then the enum can be casted to that interface

Comment: @MarkBakker: You can't have an instance of an interface.  You can have an instance of an enum, you just can't create them from the outside world.

Comment: And enums are not a replacement for static final Strings. Enums are classes, with fields and methods. they can implement interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Because an enum, by definition, has a fixed set of instances which are declared and constructed in the enum itself. Using the constructor from outside of the enum class itself thus doesn't make sense.

And AFAIK, an enum constructor is always, explicitely or implicitely, private.

Answer (score 1):

Enum is not meant to be instantiated (by you).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumTrouble.html :

> Tip: It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum because that would prevent the defined enum
>   constants from being unique. This restriction is also enforced in
>   reflective code. Code which attempts to instantiate classes using
>   their default constructors should invoke Class.isEnum() first to
>   determine if the class is an enum.

Comment: It is definitely meant to be instantiated. Not from the outside of the enum, and only a fixed number of times, though.

Comment: @JBNizet- How iwll you instantiate enum and that too fix number of times ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't dynamically extend an enum is that the instantiated values are compiled into the bytecode for the Class object:

```
public T[] getEnumConstants()
    Returns the elements of this enum class or null if this Class object does not
    represent an enum type.
```

As a result, any attempt to construct a new instance would not be able to passed onto the actual Class, since Class objects cannot be changed.  If you want this behavior, you'll have to simulate it yourself, and give it some kind of unique value to represent each one, then have an ordinal counter, and finally a static map (or some other structure) to hold all the values.

```
public class MyEnum {
  private static AtomicInteger nextOrdinal = new AtomicInteger(0);
  private static Map<Integer, MyEnum> instances =
      new HashMap<Integer, MyEnum>();

  private int ordinal;
  private String name;

  public MyEnum(String name) {
     super();
     this.ordinal = nextOrdinal.incrementAndGet();
     this.name = name;
     instances.put(Integer.valueOf(this.ordinal), this);
  }

  public String name() {
     return name;
  }

  public int ordinal() {
     return ordinal;
  }

  public static Set<MyEnum> getEnumConstants() {
     return Collections.unmodifiableSet(instances.values());
  }


  public static MyEnum fromInt(int ordinal) {
     return instances.get(Integer.valueOf(ordinal));
  }

  public static MyEnum fromString(String name) {
     for (MyEnum val : instances.values()) {
         if (val.name().equals(name)) {
             return val;
         }
     }
     return null;
  }

}
```

You'll probably also want a .equals and .hashcode method, as well as preventing the same name from being used more than once (which you could do in the constructor and throw an IllegalStateException or something if you have a duplicate name).